# Media Query - is height of viewport larger than width?

Tags: css, responsive-design, media-queries

Is it possible using CSS3 media queries to ask:

'is the height of the viewport larger than the width'?

or:

'is the width of the viewport larger than the height'?

I would like my images to be fluid in both directions!

Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For this you might use the following media queries:

```
orientation:portrait
orientation:landscape
```

I cannot give you more information on the media queries, as I haven't researched them yet. Do make sure they are supported by the devices you wish to support.

As for CSS: no, you cannot detect the width and height of your viewport using CSS. CSS is not a programming language, but a styling language. Unless you're using a CSS preprocessor (Sass, Less), you won't be able to do anything intelligent with it.

Comment: As a side note, it _should_ be possible to use `@media all and (width: 100vmax)` and `@media all and (height: 100vmax)` for width > height and height > width respectively, since the W3C recommended spec allows for all standard <length> values. At present, however, no browser seems to support this... Using both may be a non-intrusive future-proof to maximise compatibility?

Comment: I have no answer to that. However, it is important to keep in mind that techniques like mentioned above, are still being implemented and not backwards compatible in some cases (outdated browsers). I'd personally try to go for the technique that is supported among today's modern browsers and provide fallbacks if needed. (Though for browsers like IE6, I simply switched to the Universal IE6 Stylesheet by Andy Clarke.)

Answer (score 2):

Mr. Alien may be right on some technicality, because I'm not a programmer. However, if you want to redesign your layout or make adjustments based on wether the screen is in landscape (width is larger than height) or portrait (height is larger than width) mode, you can definitely use css media queries.

http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-mediaqueries/#media0