# Media query for when device height > width (and vice-versa) without using orientation property

Tags: html, css, media-queries, orientation

How would I write a media query for when the device height is larger than device width or vice-versa?

When searching I came across solutions like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10858994/css-media-query-height-greater-than-width-and-visa-versa-or-how-to-imitate-with) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14338178/media-query-is-height-of-viewport-larger-than-width) which use the `screen.orientation` property.

However, I am experiencing [this chrome issue for Windows 8](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?can=2&start=0&num=100&q=&colspec=ID%20Pri%20M%20Week%20ReleaseBlock%20Cr%20Status%20Owner%20Summary%20OS%20Modified&groupby=&sort=&id=423919) where `screen.orientation` is always undefined, and therefore I can't base my media queries off of something like `screen.orientation == landscape`

How can I achieve the same check in a media query without using `orientation`?

Thank you very much for your time. Let me know if you need any additional information or I am being unclear.

Comment: What version of Chrome are you using?

Comment: I'm actually running this app in [nw.js](http://nwjs.io/) but it uses the chromium 38 dlls. `screen.orientation` works for me on my Windows 7 machine, but not Windows 8.